# What are the scoping rules for function parameters shadowing System` symbols?

Tags: scoping, expression-manipulation, pure-function

Here are some very contrived code snippets, highly unlikely to appear in real code, but still I am curious why they behave like this:

```
Function[List, {1, 2, 3}][Hold]
(* Hold[1, 2, 3] *)

Function[Function, Function[Slot[1]]][Hold]
(* Hold[#1] *)

Function[Slot, Function[Slot[1]]][Hold]
(* Hold[1] & *)

Function[Function, Function[x, 1]][Hold]
(* Function[x, 1] *) (* Why not Hold[x, 1]? *)

{Function[Null, Null][1]}
(* {Null} *) (* Why not {1}? *)
```

I think I understand the first 3 cases.
Could you please explain the last 2 results?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the first puzzle, I can only guess. The idea is that `Function` with named variables is a true lexical scoping construct, in that it cares about the possible name collisions inside the inner scoping constructs, including another `Function`-s (this is where it is different from `Slot`- based functions, which are not like that. The price to pay is that `Slot`-based functions can not be non-trivially nested). This name collision analysis and variable renaming is happening before the variable binding - this is important.  Another important point is that generally the renaming is excessive - it is often performed even when not strictly necessary.

So, when you enter

```
Function[Function, Function[x, 1]][Hold]
```

the following should (according to my guess) roughly happen:

- The inner scoping constructs are analyzed. The named function `Function[x,1]` is detected.
- The `Function` variable in `Function[Function,...]` is renamed (just in case). We end up with something like `Function[$Function,Function[x,1]][Hold]`.
- The variable binding is performed. Effectively we have now a constant function that returns `Function[x,1]` regardless of the input. This happens because the renaming of `Function` (as a variable) to `$Function` happened before the binding stage, and therefore did not affect the body (`Function[x,1]`).
- The resulting function is called on `Hold`, and returns `Function[x,1]`, as it now should.

Now, here is how you can fool the detection mechanism (just one way out of many):

```
Function[Function,Function@@Hold[x,1]][Hold]

(* Hold[x,1] *)
```

Now the inner `Function` is not detected as a scoping construct, renaming is not performed, then the `Function` as a variable is lexically bound to the `Function` in the body, and we get the expected result.

---

The second case is simpler. Note that there is an undocumented way to enter `Slot`-based functions, such as:

```
Function[Null, body]
```

which is interpreted as `body&`. This form is needed to be able to define `Slot`-based pure functions with attributes, such as

```
Function[Null, #=1,HoldAll]
```

Now, in your case, your function is interpreted as `Null&`, so it will return `Null` on all inputs.